# Domain Resolution Rebinding Domain

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm pretty new to this so my terminology may be a bit slack.

I would like to set up a webspace that includes a number of things, a general site and forum and so on.  I wish to use DotNetNuke which after going through a few things appeals to me greatly.  My current hosting service is slow and the cost of something better seems a bit much.  My current ISP service does not include a Static IP.

What I would like to do for now to avoid expenditures is to continue using my hosting plan and their DNS to resolve to the webspace provided by them.  I would then like to rebind to my home computer on a specified port through my ISP provided Dynamic IP.  I do not want to Cloak/Mask/Forward/Rewrite as this all seems like so much effort to change xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2222/index.html to mydomain.com/index.html.  I want to maintain proper indexing and so on.

I'm not asking for the general procedure.  What I am asking is, is this even possible?  I really hate wasting hundreds of hours needlessly on trivial matters and like to avoid events like this as often as possible.  My web hosts allotted IIS AppPool crashed and I have to wait for a restart; research suggests there may have been an over consumption of resources.  I've had my site running from home and it is smooth and fast.

Comment: your site may be smooth and fast for you, but what about for everyone else? in short its more expensive for a reason... quality

Comment: I meant from external terminals, although quality is desirable I am currently limited financially.  I think I have resolved my issue though.  I will use dyndns and point at and update my external ip.  The contents at the site will be my nameserver.  Good enough for now . . . . .

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about rebinding to a specific port?  So your server is listening on :2222 but you want users to just go to http://yourdomain.com and that transparently connect to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:222/ ?

Comment: @Paul my ISP blocks Port 80 so I need to use another port.  And yes I would like to transparently connect with proper indexing and without the use of frames.

Comment: dyndns does not allow port specification in their pro service :/

Comment: Ah.  Ignore my answer below for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get your home server listening on port 80 this is straightforward.

1. Use dyndns to set up a domain name for your site (yoursite.dyndns.org)
2. Go to your host control panel for DNS and set up a cname:

   yoursite.com. CNAME yoursite.dyndns.org
    www.yoursite.com. CNAME yoursite.dyndns.org

What this is say is that anyone who tries to get the IP for yoursite.com should instead get the IP address for yoursite.dyndns.org - which will be your IP address.

If you cannot listen on port 80, then a reverse proxy is the only way you can do this.  Rewriting is not an option because you cannnot rewrite to another server transparently.  Apache can do reverse proxies, but it is very unlikely that your host will enable this feature.  So your only option is to code a [php based reverse proxy](http://demo.loopip.com/integration_demo/search/php_reverse_proxy).  Of course, then you are relying on the speed of your host to do the proxying (not to mention setting up a proxy is often against ts&cs.

Comment: Thanks!  I will definitely look into a reverse proxy.  Maybe something in ASP.NET :D